# display the data from UIView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I need to display the data in the UIView.I created a class name as:-
MYView-UIView

```
  import UIKit

    class MYView: UIView {
        @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

 func setlisttabData(chefs:listModel)
   {
        self.name.text = chefs.name
    }

    }
```

And My viewcontroller as :-

```
import UIKit

class listViewController: UIViewController {
    //  @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var chef: MYView!

    private var listViewModel :ListViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:ListViewModel) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        listViewModel  = viewModel
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

in this I have not used main storyboard.
So for `listViewController` I have .xib

In the xib I have placed the scroll view and a view in that. In the view I given the class name as MYView. Then I have placed a label in that. And given the connections.

Now I need to display the name .How to do.

I have given a function in UIView as:

```
func setlisttabData(chefs:listModel){
    self.name.text = chefs.name
}
```

modelclass:-
import UIKit

```
class listModel: NSObject {



    var name:String!

    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else {
                return
        }

        self.name = name
      }  
    }

 my listviewmodel:-


class listviewmodel: NSObject {



    var datasourceModel:listDataModel

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: listDataModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> listModel{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }


    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }


}
```

and listdatasourcemodel:-

```
class listDataModel: NSObject {


    var dataListArray:Array<listModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored3()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<listModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = listModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }



}

typealias dummyDataSource3 =  listDataModel
extension dummyDataSource3{

    func getJsonDataStored3() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["name":"Anjapar"] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }





}
```

i got the value in model .But i think for this below function something needed to change.

```
 func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> listModel{
            return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

        }
```

I need to get the name from that jsondictionary.

So, how to call in ViewController. This had done in mvvm method.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @PPL i not getting the name.how to call the function setlisttabData in the viewcontroller

Comment: are you getting the chef IBOutlet? please check the name is not nil

Comment: @PPL i have updated my code .please check.i have given the func setlistData in MYView class

Comment: are you getting listmodel from datafordisplay? or in this method, setlisttabData, check listmodel had name not nil

Comment: @PPL i have the data   in :- let jsonArray = [["name":"Anjapar","location":"india","videourl":"","chefname":"rahul"]as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>So,what should give in the datafordisplay function.i getting the values in the listmodel.

Comment: @PPL how to get the values

Comment: so listmodel should have name, location, videourl and chefname attributes in it, am I right?

Comment: @yes.i getting the values in the listmodel.

Comment: then it should work. please debug and see that method called or not? the name IBOutlet should not be nil

Comment: @PPL WHERE should call the method .The values not getting

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like:

```
self.chef.setlisttabData(listViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray)
```

Comment: arrchefs from where

Comment: but here showing an error as:-cannot convert the type of 'Array<listmodel>?to exprected argument type 'listmodel'

Comment: i need to call the func datafordisplay method.how to do

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **delegation**.
1. Create a protocol having a function declaration.
2. Implement the function in viewController by extending the viewController class by the protocol.
3. Take the reference of protocol in `UIView` class.

```
weak  var delegate: YourProtocol?
```

4. Set `UIView` delegate in viewController

   ```
   view.delegate = self
   ```
5. Call delegate function in `UIView` class where you want to. This will call UIViewController protocol function.

For better understanding of **delegation**, you can read [**this**](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)