# display the data in UIViewController

Tags: ios

I need to display the name ,location,place,phone no in a UIView.
I am not using the main storyboard.

I have a UIViewcontroller class

example here a demo image is uploaded .please check.

[I need to display the data in UIView as screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8zgM.gif)

ListViewController.swift and ListViewController.xib file
How to do ?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad i have tried as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664340/display-the-data-from-uiview-to-uiviewcontroller  but not got the values

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad how to solve the problem

Comment: Why are you not using a UIViewController and the Storyboard?  Writing everything in code is much better for understanding, but much more difficult for someone just starting out.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon i need to do this in without  main storyboard.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad i have updated my  question .please check

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete your `MainStoryboard` file then remove `MainStoryboard` from `infoPlist`.After that make your `ListViewController` as a `rootViewController` in `AppDelegate` like that:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let listViewController = ListViewController().init(nibName:"ListViewController", bundle:nil) as ListViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = listViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
return true
}
```

then design your view in `.xib` you can take help from [link](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/xcode-basics.html)